# JS async / await with fetch doesn't work like PHP include for JSON file

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

This code below works in PHP but not in JS. Can you tell me why? **How can I make the pure JS version work?**

```
async function cccrFlow() {
    response = await fetch('assets/club_mems.json');
    club_mems = [];
    club_mems = await response.json(); // DOESN"T WORK
}

function cccrFlow() {
    club_mems = <?php include('assets/club_mems.json');?>; //  WORKS PERFECTLY
}
```

## club_mems.json

```
[{"Name":"Ahmedistan, Jamshed","clubEXP":"2022-09-15"},{"Name":"Anaizi, Paul N","clubEXP":"2021-01-27"},{"Name":"Anderson, Simon","clubEXP":"2022-06-30"},{"Name":"Ashes, Bob P","clubEXP":"2022-04-21"}]
```

Comment: Because PHP executes code in sync and way before any content is served to browser. Basically your second example JS sees only direct output.

Comment: So would you advise staying with the php version eschewing the async/await version?

Comment: could you provide us with logs? browser should've reported something in the console had it encountered any errors

Comment: How do you know the JS version does not work? You could do `console.log(response.status, club_mems);` for us.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use fetch, you have to make sure that whatever asset/resource you are loading - is publicly accessible. In short,

if you use this URL in browser `http://yourserver.com/assets/club_mems.json` and you can see the response in the browser, then your `fetch/async/await` will work (see screenshot).

If you don't want to expose your data in public domain, then you will have to include the JSON file using one of the module loading methods i.e. `import/require`.

**EDIT**

To achieve this: you need to have some kind of module loader in your development environment. The module loader will make sure that once you build your application for prod environment, your code includes the JSON data without any issue.

There are different options: webpack, bundlr, parcel etc. Checkout their official websites for how to set them.

Once you set this up, you can simply write in your code:

```
const jsonData = require("/path/to/club_mems.json");

or

import jsonData from "/path/to/club_mems.json"
```

[image: access JSON file]

Comment: How do I include the JSON file using one of the module loading methods i.e. import/requre?

Comment: I updated my answer, see the edit section.

Answer (score -1):

**try this solution:**

```
function cccrFlow() {
    club_mems = fetch('assets/club_mems.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
        alert(data);
    })
}
```

Comment: I wanted to use async and await with the fetch.

Comment: I think this link helpful for you 
https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-fetch-async-await/